# React Hook Form Not Working with Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, next.js13

I'm working on a project and trying to use React-Hook-Form with Next.js 13 But the Submit button is not working. It appears that the onSubmit / handleSubmit is not getting called.

Below is my Form Component:

```
"use client"
import '../app/contact-us/index.css'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'

type FormValues = {
    first_name: string
    last_name: string
    email: string
    number: number
    message: string
}:
```

The functional component

```
export default function ContactForm () {
    const form = useForm<FormValues>();
    const {register, handleSubmit} = form;

    const submitForm = (data: FormValues) => {
        console.log(data)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form action="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
                        <div className='form-row'>
                        <input {...register("first_name")} required pattern="^[A-Za-z]{3,16}$" type="text" id="first_name" placeholder='First Name' />
                        <input {...register("last_name")} required pattern="^[A-Za-z]{3,16}$" type="text" id="last_name" placeholder='Last Name' />
                        </div>
                        <div className='form-row'>
                        <input {...register("number")} type="tel" name="number" id="number" placeholder='Phone Number' />
                        <input {...register("email")} type="email" id="email" placeholder='lucky01@gmail.com' />
                        <span id='emailError'></span>
                        </div>
                        <textarea {...register("message")} id="message" rows={15}></textarea>
                        <input className='submit-btn' type="button" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your inputs inside the form element are `type="submit"`. That's why the submit event won't fire. You need to set `type="submit"` on your `className='submit-btn'` button instead of `type="button"`.

Comment: My Bad! How did I miss that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have a button of type submit in the form to send the data

Comment: Please note that when making answers elaborate it more with sources until you get the privilege to comment to the questions. In fact, your response belongs to comments.